# Solving $2-4\sin 2 \theta = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Which of the following represents zeros of $r=2-4\sin 2 \theta $? (Multiple choice)

I don't understand this question. I figured out that $\theta$ is $30$, and I determined that the answer is
$A$ (i.e. $\pi/6$ and $5\pi/6$).
However, the answer sheet tells me that
$D$ (i.e. $\pi/12$, $5\pi/12$, $13\pi/12$, $17\pi/12$)
is correct. I don't understand how $13\pi/12$ and $17\pi/12$ are possible answer for this question.

Comment: Sorry., ignore the last comment. Missed the second $2.$

Comment: Welcome to Math.Stackexchange!
Images containing crucial parts of the exercise are discouraged on MSE for a vareity of reasons.  If you ask nicely, someone may retype the image into your question for you.  To ensure your question is not deleted or downvoted you may need to type it in yourself.  Try the edit button directly underneath your question and left of your name.

Comment: $2-4\sin\left(2\dfrac{13\pi}{12}\right)=2-4\sin\dfrac{13\pi}6=2-4\sin\dfrac{\pi}6=2-4\times\dfrac12=0$

Comment: How did you get $\theta = 30^o$? Did you miss the $2$ in $2\theta$?

Comment: David, I'm sorry on behalf of Math.SE.  The website is highly biased towards upper level undergraduate and higher math.  I thought your question was quite legitimate here and reasonably well written.  For future reference it helps if you have it up to Math.SE standards before posting to the whole community.

Plus, 95% of what you learn in high school (I'm guessing your school level) will be considered homework, which Math.SE may not look favorably upon.

You can try to get the question reopened if you like.
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question

Comment: David, I am pretty sure that your question was not closed because of its level, and helping pupils for their homework is frequent on Math.SE, provided they show their attempts with enough detail. Here it was nearly the case, except that you didn't react to Benjamin's comment (by a comment, or better: an edit of your post).

Answer (score 2):

$\theta$ is not 30°.
Most likely your mistake is forgetting the 2 from $2\theta$.
It should become the following.
$$\frac12 = \sin2\theta$$
$$30° = 2\theta \text{ or } 150° = 2\theta \text{**}$$ See *** below.
Then we must divide by two on both of sides of each equation.
$$\frac{30}{2} = 15° = \theta \text{ or } \frac{150}{2} =75° = \theta $$
Converting to radians this is $$\theta =\frac{\pi}{12}\text{ or }\frac{5\pi}{12}$$
This gives us two of the four answers in D.
Note: (***)To get the other two answers in D, first we remember about coterminal angles.
Let k be any integer.
Essentially, for the first angle,
$$2\theta = 30° = \frac{\pi}{6}\text{ becomes }2\theta = 30° +360°k= \frac{\pi}{6} + 2\pi \cdot k$$ all point the exact same direction, so give the same result after taking the sine, for any integer we choose to use for k.  Likewise, for the second angle,
$$2\theta = 150° = \frac{5\pi}{6}\text{ becomes }2\theta = 150° +360k= \frac{5\pi}{6} + 2\pi \cdot k$$

Applying this to (**) from above and dividing each term by two again,
$$\theta = 15° +180°k= \frac{\pi}{12} + \pi \cdot k \text{ or }\theta = 75° +180°k= \frac{5\pi}{12} + \pi \cdot k$$
Many problems specify, $0\leq\pi < \theta < 2\pi$ or sometimes the textbook or teacher will specify assume $\theta$ has this restriction for large portions of the course.  To meet that restriction, choose $k =0$ and choose $k=1$, we finally get $$D=\dfrac {\pi}{12}, \dfrac {5\pi}{12}, \dfrac {13\pi}{12}, \dfrac {17\pi}{12}$$

Comment: If anyone would like to edit my last line into proper fraction format, degree signs throughout, etc. feel free

Comment: @davidSmith If you don't understand any part of this please ask for clarification.
Otherwise, would you consider, accepting the answer.
https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Done!  I used ALT+0176 for the degree sign and \dfrac for the fractions.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by Benjamin, you seem to have `missed the $2$ in $2\theta$'.

The following solution uses the notation $a\equiv b\bmod c$, which  means: $a=b+kc$ for some $k\in\Bbb Z$.

$$\begin{align}\sin(2\theta)=\frac12&\iff2\theta\equiv\pi/6\text{ or }5\pi/6\bmod{2\pi}\\
&\iff\theta\equiv\pi/12\text{ or }5\pi/12\bmod\pi\\&\iff\theta\equiv\pi/12\text{ or }\pi/12+\pi\text{ or }5\pi/12
\text{ or }5\pi/12+\pi\bmod{2\pi}.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Overall you've given, a much simpler answer than mine, which I'm sure some students will find useful.  May I offer a suggestion?  The typical trig student may not have ever heard of mod.  At least in the US, mod *may not* be covered until a university junior level course like Discrete Math, which is mostly only taken by Computer Science majors or Number Theory, which is mostly only math majors.

Comment: I was suggesting to remove the mod.  The typical way this is taught, at least in American high schools, is to use k throughout.  See how my answer has no mod anywhere in the question?

Comment: @nickalh This is precisely what I wanted to avoid, so I rolled back (moreover, your rewriting was not rigorous: strictly speaking, $ \theta=\frac{\pi}{12} + \pi k\  \text{ or }\ \frac{5\pi}{12}+ \pi k$ is *not* equivalent to $\theta=\frac{\pi}{12},\ \frac{\pi}{12}+\pi, \ \frac{5\pi}{12}
\ \text{ or }\ \frac{5\pi}{12}+\pi$). I prefer to keep it simple. Once the mod is defined, this answer is easy to follow. Readers are free to prefer yours.

Comment: I've never seen a trig. student approach that level of rigor.  Calculus maybe, not for trig.  To each their own.

Comment: $\bmod{2\pi}$ is particularly convenient when solving such trigonometric equations. Too bad for those pupils or students (all over the world, since .SE is international) which were not yet provided this simple tool. It is a good reason to offer them this short definition and quick example of its efficiency.